# UNITY UI Lag when Instance a game object in ios8

Tags: unity-game-engine, ios8

I have strange problem running my game.

My device : iphone 6+ ios 8.4

Unity: 5.1.1p4

Xcode: 6.4

In IOS8, when i Instance a gameobject from a prefab which contain canvas and UI object. it is very lag, slow.
if i deleted all ui object in prefab. it is not lag any more.

In ios7, It's not lag for both of case.

someone HELP me.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating is expensive in general and I often get the same problem even on PC. You need to Instantiate the stuff at the start of the scene and deactivate them. Then just activate them later on instead of instantiating. If you need to instantiate many things, try making an instance pool and grabbing unused objects from that pool and only instantiate new things when the pool is empty.